# Not Able to Register app using SCDF 2.11.2 Dashboard UI due to one mandatory field (Spring boot version) which is disabled in my Application

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

Recently Upgraded Spring cloud dataflow from 2.9.2 to 2.11.2. After the upgrade, all the existing apps were cleaned up don't know how.

But, now I am trying to import or register these apps using the dashboard UI screen. Previously you didn't have to specify the spring boot version in that field but this new field is introduced which is a mandatory field for regeistering the apps.

But I don't know why this field called spring boot version is disabled for me, hence not able to register the app. This is a blocker for me. let me know if I am missing anything. (any config)

locally this option is visible but not on the Kubernetes cluster.

I am using docker URI to import the apps.

[image]
I tried importing the app, but I don't have any other option.